# PostgreSQL - Deleting a database with forward slash in its name

Tags: postgresql

In my Ruby-on-Rails `database.yml` file, I accidentally created a PostgreSQL database with a forward slash (`/`) in its name.

I have been unable to remove this database via psql commands, trying with various escape sequences.

Comment: @DanielNova: \ is a *back* slash, a forward slash is this: `/`. You might want to re-think your edit.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Haha, yeah that was a bit of a fail, I blame lack of sleep.

Answer (score 7):

Surround your database name in quotes:

```
DROP DATABASE "database/withslash";
```

From the [Identifiers and Keywords](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) documentation:

> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of characters in double-quotes ("). A delimited identifier is always an identifier, never a key word. So "select" could be used to refer to a column or table named "select", whereas an unquoted select would be taken as a key word and would therefore provoke a parse error when used where a table or column name is expected. The example can be written with quoted identifiers like this:
>
> ```
> UPDATE "my_table" SET "a" = 5;
> ```
>
> Quoted identifiers can contain any character, except the character with code zero.

Do note that quoted identifiers are case sensitive.

You cannot drop a database while connected *to* that database though, so maybe you want to use the command line [`dropdb` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/app-dropdb.html). Your shell will parse the quotes, so you want to escape the quotes:

```
dropdb \"database/withslash\"
```

Comment: Hi. Maybe in my original question I wrote backslash...however, what I meant was forward slash, and in this case I'm trying to delete a database whose name contains a forward slash (not a table). Regards, Allan.

Comment: @lagouyn: ah, it was late for me as well. :-) Updated.